# How to convert a Mat (OpenCV) to INDArray (DL4J)?

Tags: opencv, keras, mat

I have a keras network model that takes INDArray but I don't know how to convert a Mat to an INDArray. I know that this is the same question of [How to convert Mat (opencv) to INDArray (DL4J)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048041/how-to-convert-mat-opencv-to-indarray-dl4j) but it did not help me. Is there some API that performs this task? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NativeImageLoader` for the conversion.

```
import org.datavec.image.loader.NativeImageLoader;



(...)
        Mat cvImage();

        // Fill in your Mat with something

        NativeImageLoader nil = new NativeImageLoader();
        INDArray image = nil.asMatrix(cvImage).div;
```

Make sure you have the dependency for datavec in your `pom.xml`. What error do you get?